# Algorithm to travel most cities by a fixed distance?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Say I'm a runner, ran a fixed distance of 42KM, no more, no less.

There are a couple of cities (or shops if you think distances between cities are normally bigger than 42KM) can be traversed in this range.

**You can start from ANY vertex(city), how to schedule a route so that I can reach the most number of cities? The runner visit each city exactly once and returns to the origin city. (When the runner returned to the original point, the KMs he ran could be smaller than 42KM)**

In real world, this graph should be a cyclic able, non-directed, weighted graph.

However, you are welcome to give any opinion including changing the constraints.

**Edit:**

I had a brute force solution as follows, still trying to find out a better solution.

(1) setup a collection of possible result set (E.g. 4 cities, a, b, c, d; then I get a combination of 2 cities[ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd], 3 cities[abc,abd,acd,bcd], 4 cities[abcd]);

(2) run TSP on each of this result, the result is a distance; if this distance is smaller than 42KM, this result is a candidate.

(3) from the candidate list, choose the one with most cities. This is a brute force solution, however.

Comment: See the Traveling salesman problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: I understand TSP, however, the runner is not interested to travel all the cities, he is just willing to travel MOST NUMBER of cities in a fixed distance. I tried to proof this is a variant of TSP but can not.

Comment: People downvoting and/or voting to close? Puzzling...

Comment: @erickson I noticed someone down voted once and some one up voted to pull it back. I'm actually puzzled at your questions. Hopefully, you are not giving suggestion to close this one. Personally, I know some basic graph algorithm  and I guess this one fell into "Approximation Algorithms"; however, I can not find a solution to it (not to mention efficient solution).

Comment: If you had an efficient algorithm for this you could use it to solve TSP by running it with different distances, using binary chop to find the distance at which you can just visit all the cities. So it is indeed a variant of TSP.

Comment: @mcdowella You inspired me. At least I could get a solution (not efficient at all). (1) setup a collection of possible result set (E.g. 4 cities, a, b, c, d; then I get a combination of 2 cities[ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd], 3 cities[abc,abd,acd,bcd], 4 cities[abcd]); (2) run TSP on each of this result, the result is a distance; if this distance is smaller than 42KM, this result is a candidate. (3) from the candidate list, choose the one with most cities. This is a brute force solution, however.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I was questioning why anyone would downvote a valid and interesting question, or suggest that a well-defined problem like this was "too broad." Perhaps it was before your edits.

Comment: Is the runner allowed to visit a city more than once?

Comment: Does the runner needs to return to the origin city after 42 KM?

Comment: @ead When the runner returned to the original point, the KMs he ran could be smaller than 42KM. This made this possible "The runner visit each city exactly once and returns to the origin city. "